# Python-Take multiple inputs using for loop and print multiple outputs through if condition

Tags: python

This is my code which prints if a number can be divided into two even numbers.

```
`n=int(input("Enter no. of variables:"))
for i in range(n):
    a = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
for x in a:
    if(x%2==0):
        print("Yes")
    elif(x==2 or x==0):
        print("No")
    else:
        print("No")`
```

I am getting the output as

`Enter no. of variables:2
4
6
Yes`

Only the last number entered is giving the result,
I need the output as

`Enter no. of variables:2
4
6
Yes
Yes`

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving your input incorrectly. Try this:

```
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append(int(input()))
```

Or, as a list comprehension:

```
a = [int(input()) for i in range(n)]
```

Also, if you want to test if a number can be split into two even numbers, try `x % 4` instead of `x % 2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(n):
    a = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
```

Each time through this loop, you're reassigning `a`, discarding its previous value.

Comment: if i indent the second for loop into the first the output is Enter no. of variables2
4
Yes
6
Yes

Comment: but i need it as Enter no. of variables:2
4
6
Yes
Yes

Answer (score 0):

In your first loop, you're replacing each input list result with a *new* input list.

The culprit:

```
    a = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
```

When your code exits the loop, `a` will only contain one value. To revise your approach, you could initialise a list before the loop, appending values into it *when inside the loop*.

```
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append(int(input()))
```

Additionally, since there seems to be only one number per line, simply doing `int(input())` will get the number.

Your second loop might also need to be revised.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
a=[]
n=int(input("Enter no. of variables:"))
for i in range(n):
    a += list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
    print(a)
for x in a:
    if(x%2==0):
        print("Yes")
    elif(x==2 or x==0):
        print("No")
    else:
        print("No")
```

Python overwrites the value of a with the input each time, but I think what you want is for these values to accumulate. += accomplishes this with lists.

Let me know if this helps!

edit: I put the three code ticks on the same line as some of my code, so it got eaten by them.

Answer (score 0):

In your beginning loop you keep resetting the value of `a` instead of adding it to the existing value of `a`:

```
for i in range(n):
    a = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
```

The first time `a = [4]` but then you override it the next loop where `a = [6]`

To append it to `a` instead, you should do:

```
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a += list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
```

or what you are more likely going for:

```
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append(int(input().rstrip()))
```

The way you are doing it, calling `.split()` on the input generates a list which wouldn't make sense in this case, if would be better to just get the number by `int(input().rstrip())`

Another way to do it is using list comprehension which is more pythonic:

```
a = [int(input().rstrip()) for _ in range(n)]
```

Hope that helps!